# Building forms in React which know the value of all input fields

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs

I'm creating a form where each input is added manually with each new form instance like so:

```
class Demo extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
            <MultiInputForm title='Super Cool Form'>
                <FormRow>
                    <FormInput type='select' label='first' options={['cool','sweet']} />
                    <FormInput type='select' label='second' options={['nice','awesome']} />
                </FormRow>
            </MultiInputForm>
    )
}
}
```

But I'm having trouble figuring out how to gather all my input states for submission at the end of the form. Right now I'm changing the state on each input, but I don't know the best way (or any way) to access them onSubmit of the form. Here are my components (FormRow is just a simple container/organizer for now and is mostly ignorable):

```
var FormInput = React.createClass({
valueChange(e){
    this.setState(value: e.target.value);
},
render(){
    switch(this.props.type){
        case "select":
            var optionArray = [];
            for(var val of this.props.options)
            {
                optionArray.push(<option>{val}</option>);
            }

            return (
                <div>
                    <label>{this.props.label}</label>
                    <select onChange={this.valueChange}>{optionArray}</select>
                </div>
            )
            break;
        default:
            return <div />
    }
}
})

var MultiInputForm = React.createClass({
getInitialState(){
    return {};
},
handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var formValues = this.state;
    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        type:"POST",
        data:{vals:formValues},
        success(response,status,xhr){

        },
        error(err,status,xhr){

        }
    })
},
render(){
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            {this.props.children}
            <input type="submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
})

var FormRow = React.createClass({
render(){
    return (
        <div>
            {this.props.children}
        </div>
    )
}
})
```

I've seen a way where people create the form inputs within the render method of the form using a list of names for each input via props and programmatically build them from that list (therefore being able to make onChange for each input point to the parent form's method of handling change/state), but my inputs are more complicated than just a name (I will be making a switch case for several different kinds of inputs) and so the only ways I could see feasibly building my forms is by either making the children inputs manually, as I've done here, or by passing an array of big objects to the form to create the inputs from. But I thought that way would get too unwieldy.

So to summarize: How best to gather information from a family of components? Or, how best to structure a family of components to keep their information in one place?

Answer (score 0):

What you really want is the `valueChange` handler to be in `MultiForm` and passed into each `FormInput` in props. Since you can't do this in your `Demo` component  you could use `cloneElement` to add that handler to the props of each child:

```
var MultiInputForm = React.createClass({
    // ...
    componentWillMount() {
        var state = {};
        // get initial field values:
        React.Children.forEach(this.props.children, function(child) {
            state[child.props.label] = child.props.defaultValue || null
        }, this);
        this.setState(state);
    }
    inputChanged(field, newValue) {
        this.setState({[field]: newValue});
    }
    render() {
        var newChildren = React.Children.map(this.props.children, function(child) {
            return React.cloneElement(child, { inputChanged: this.inputChanged });
        }, this);
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    {newChildren}
                    <input type="submit" />
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Now you can update FormInput to call the inputChanged handler passed in via props:

```
var FormInput = React.createClass({
    valueChange(e) {
        this.inputChanged(this.props.label, e.target.value)
    }
    render() {
        switch(this.props.type){
            case "select":
                var optionArray = [];
                    for(var val of this.props.options) {
                        optionArray.push(<option>{val}</option>);
                    }

                return (
                    <div>
                        <label>{this.props.label}</label>
                        <select onChange={this.valueChange}>{optionArray}</select>
                    </div>
                )
            default:
                return <div />
        }
    }
})
```

You can read about `cloneElement` here: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/03/03/react-v0.13-rc2.html#react.cloneelement